# Undefined columns selected - R

Tags: r, undefined

I copied this from an exercise I'm supposed to do.

```
BirdBrains <-read.csv("~/NTNU/ST0103/BirdBrains.csv")

Names <-c("Order", "Family", "Species.name.")
Variables <-c("Maximum.lifespan", "Age.at.first.reprodction", "Incubation.length",
              "Clutch.size", "Mean.latitude", "logBodyMass", "logBrainMass")
BirdClutch <- BirdBrains[,c(Names,Variables)]
```

I get this error message:

> ```
> Error in `[.data.frame`(BirdBrains, , c(Names, Variables)) : 
>   undefined columns selected
> ```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: You probably mispelled something. Maybe 'reprodction'?

Comment: hard to say without an example of the csv